# Issues installing StrongLoop LoopBack in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to install StrongLoop LoopBack in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The installation through console always keeps on doing this. This is my output from console. Is everything going right here? Help me solve it. I couldn't complete the strongloop install in my laptop.

```
sarnathkj@SARAN:~$ sudo npm install -g strongloop
[sudo] password for sarnathkj: 

> heapdump@0.2.10 install /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/heapdump/src/heapdump.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/heapdump/src/platform-posix.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/heapdump.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/heapdump.node: Finished
  COPY Release/heapdump.node
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump/build'

> strong-fork-syslog@1.2.3 install /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/strong-fork-syslog
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/strong-fork-syslog/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/syslog/syslog.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/syslog.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/syslog.node: Finished
  COPY Release/syslog.node
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/strong-fork-syslog/build'

> strong-agent@1.3.2 install /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent
> node-gyp rebuild || exit 0

make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/strong-agent/src/strong-agent.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/strong-agent.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/strong-agent.node: Finished
  COPY Release/strong-agent.node
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/build'

> ws@0.4.32 install /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

Comment: Is that output complete? There are no errors, which normally suggests a successful install.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had the same issue with node v0.12.0, v0.12.1, npm v2.5.1 and same operating system. Installation seems to hang but if you press enter couple of times its responsive again and you get into the shell.

After that you will notice that for some reason symbolic links are not being created but the module seems to be installed correctly. To fix this I have created the sym links manually like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc /usr/local/bin/
```

This will enable you to use slc cli across the machine. Also, if you are using loopback-sdk-angular-cli which containes lb-ng and lb-ng-doc commands (which should be installed with npm install -g strongloop) you need to create those symlinks aswell. You do that like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-sdk-angular-cli/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```

This will enable you to use lb-ng across the machine, however it could happen as well that the tool will be broken with missing dependency errors. To fix those, enter to the path where module installed and execute npm install to install dependencies. On ubuntu 14.04 LTS you do that like this:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-sdk-angular-cli
npm install
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

StrongLoop seems to need a recent version of `node` and `npm`.

What are your `node` & `npm` versions (from `node --version` and `npm --version`) ?

You can refer to StrongLoop's "Installation troubleshooting" page [here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SL/Installation+troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related the version of npm you use. I also ran into this problem, I was using nvm to install node and npm. I solved the problem by installing the latest npm using `apt-get install npm`. Just have a try

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, not able to install strongloop in node version 0.12.x.
So I installed node ver0.10.40, then npm and was able to install strongloop.

Running on node ver 4 is smooth btw.

I'm also using Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 0):

Anoop ... you say ver 4 but you mean 0.10.4, correct?

We haven't gotten it going on 4.2.2 yet on Ubuntu (on Cloud9) ... but it works great on Fedora (local)